# CONCAT with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am definitely not seeing the issue as to why this isn't working. Any ideas on possibilities?

```
$this->db->select(CONCAT_WS(' ', 'users.first_name', 'users.last_name') 'AS name');
```

EDIT:

I updated with the suggested line but for some reason I'm still getting an error.

```
function getAllMessages($user_id)
{
    $this->db->select('pm.id');
    $this->db->select('pm.subject');
    $this->db->select("CONCAT_WS(' ', users.first_name, users.last_name) AS name");
    $this->db->select("DATE_FORMAT('pm.date_sent', '%M %D, %Y'");
    $this->db->select('pm.message_read');
    $this->db->from('users_personal_messages AS pm');
    $this->db->join('users', 'users.user_id = pm.sender_id');
    $this->db->where('recipient_id', $user_id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        return $query->result();;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

```
function getAllMessages($user_id)
{
    $this->db->select('pm.id');
    $this->db->select('pm.subject');
    $this->db->select("CONCAT_WS(' ', users.first_name, users.last_name) AS name");
    $this->db->select("DATE_FORMAT('pm.date_sent', '%M %D, %Y')");
    $this->db->select('pm.message_read');
    $this->db->from('users_personal_messages AS pm');
    $this->db->join('users', 'users.user_id = pm.sender_id');
    $this->db->where('recipient_id', $user_id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        return $query->result();;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

SECOND UPDATE:

```
function getAllMessages($user_id)
{
    $this->db->select('pm.id');
    $this->db->select('pm.subject');
    $this->db->select("CONCAT_WS(' ', users.first_name, users.last_name) AS name");
    $this->db->select(DATE_FORMAT(pm.date_sent, '%M %D, %Y'));
    $this->db->select('pm.message_read');
    $this->db->from('users_personal_messages AS pm');
    $this->db->join('users', 'users.user_id = pm.sender_id');
    $this->db->where('recipient_id', $user_id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        return $query->result();;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: `CONCAT_WS` is a MYSQL function--not something PHP will recognize. You'll want to treat it as such

Comment: Have you tried `$this->db->select("CONCAT_WS(' ', users.first_name, users.last_name) AS name", FALSE);`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to quote the string properly. Column names should not be quoted, however the whole string parameter to `select()` must be quoted.

```
$this->db->select("CONCAT_WS(' ', users.first_name, users.last_name) AS name");
```

See the [CodeIgniter `select()` docs](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html#select) for lots of examples...

#### Update

Your error is a missing parenthesis on the `DATE_FORMAT()` line:

```
$this->db->select("DATE_FORMAT(pm.date_sent, '%M %D, %Y')");
//------------------------------------------------------^^^^
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM (`users_personal_messages` AS pm) JOIN `users` ON `users`.`user_id` = `pm`.' at line 2

SELECT `pm`.`id`, `pm`.`subject`, CONCAT_WS(' ', `users`.`first_name`, `users`.`last_name)` AS name, `pm`.`message_read` FROM (`users_personal_messages` AS pm) JOIN `users` ON `users`.`user_id` = `pm`.`sender_id` WHERE `recipient_id` = '10000'

Comment: @user1244239 The error is a missing `)` on `DATE_FORMAT()` see above.

Comment: You can tell, because the error points to the start of the `FROM` clause as the problem area.

Comment: Updated code. WOW this is frustrating. I don't know why but now its saying You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM (`users_personal_messages` AS pm) JOIN `users` ON `users`.`user_id` = `pm`.' at line 2

SELECT `pm`.`id`, `pm`.`subject`, CONCAT_WS(' ', `users`.`first_name`, `users`.`last_name)` AS name, DATE_FORMAT('pm.date_sent', `'%M` %D, `%Y')`, `pm`.`message_read` FROM (`users_personal_messages` AS pm) JOIN `users` ON `users`.`user_id` = `pm`.`sender_id` WHERE `recipient_id` = '10000'

Comment: @user1244239 Oops - didn't see the quotes around `pm.date_sent` in the `DATE_FORMAT()` call. Remove them.  Never quote column or table names with single quotes.

Comment: @user1244239 Just as with the initial issue of `CONCAT()`, you lost your quotes around the whole string in `DATE_FORMAT()`. Make yours look exactly like mine above.

Comment: ou have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM (`users_personal_messages` AS pm) JOIN `users` ON `users`.`user_id` = `pm`.' at line 2

SELECT `pm`.`id`, `pm`.`subject`, CONCAT_WS(' ', `users`.`first_name`, `users`.`last_name)` AS name, DATE_FORMAT(pm.date_sent, `'%M` %D, `%Y')`, `pm`.`message_read` FROM (`users_personal_messages` AS pm) JOIN `users` ON `users`.`user_id` = `pm`.`sender_id` WHERE `recipient_id` = '10000'

Comment: Better yet is there another way I can handle this situation.

Comment: @user1244239 Don't really know what to tell you. There's no syntax error here I can see.

Comment: Thanks for your help though. I"m going to try and just do this with php instead of mysql.

Comment: Could you post the full problematic sql query? Sorry if you already did, but I don't see that in your updated post.

Comment: @andreas It's in one of the OP's comments above as codeigniter creates it.

Answer (score 0):

Change this
$this->db->select("CONCAT_WS(' ', users.first_name, users.last_name) AS name");
with this
$this->db->select("CONCAT_WS(' ', users.first_name, users.last_name) AS name",FALSE);